# Is type theory compatible with n-ary branching?

Tags: syntax, type-theory, branching

The question by curiousdannii and the extensive answer by lemontree [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/35341/what-explanatory-advantages-does-so-called-type-theory-have) address the basic workings, advantages, and disadvantages of type theory. I have a related question in this area. As I understand type theory and as described by lemontree, type theory necessarily construes syntactic structures as being generated in terms of one input and one output. This suggests that the syntactic structures generated necessitate binary branching; ternary branching does not seem possible, at least not in the illustrations of type theory that I have encountered.

My question in this regard concerns the potential that this aspect of type theory can be chalked up to the disadvantages. For me, there is substantial empirical evidence in favor of n-ary branching in syntactic structures. If type theory is incompatible with this evidence, then what good is it? It results in a semantics that is incompatible with the syntax.

If there are versions of type theory that are compatible with n-ary branching, then what are they, and how widespread and accepted are those versions?

Comment: I can only speak as a computer scientist here, but you can always just extend the simply typed lambda calculus with a family of product types (such that for all `x1 : t1, ..., xn : tn`, `prod(x1, ..., xn) : t1 * ... * tn`, plus projections `pi_n_i : (t1 * ... * tn) -> ti`).

Comment: Oh, and have you heard about [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)?

Comment: @phipsgabler Product types won’t help here because they’re ordered (otherwise there would be no isomorphism in the first place). In CS parlance, semanticists use associative arrays which give them named arguments. This is what’s used in LFG and other formalisms based on feature structures (AVMs), as explained in the answer below.

Comment: Hm. I'd really like to sit together with a couple of these semanticists once and query from them what they actually mean in terms of concepts I can think in... for now it seems I don't even know how to start asking what I misunderstand :)

Comment: @phipsgabler I think it’s simply two distinct worlds. Linguists started using the λ-calculus, then they realised it didn’t work well with the formal tools they already had (phrase structure or categorial grammars) and went on to invent their own notation, which turned out to be a dumbed down version of category theory. They don’t care much about the maths that underlies the formalisms (such as glue semantics) as long as it meshes well with their parses :)

Comment: Everything formal is just dumbed down category theory :P But what I meant is: there must be some nontrivial benefit of the formalisms linguists use, too -- that I just cannot see yet. On the other hand, I dare not ask a the question "explain this 'type theory'  thing to me in terms of typed lambda calculi and deduction rules", fearing it would be closed as too general. Could you maybe point me to resources?

Comment: @phipsgabler You might want to read the original papers on Montague’s grammar (the wiki page has references). Then I’d recommend looking at glue semantics which combines λ-calculus and linear logic (and syntactic structures based on dependencies), there are a few good papers by Mary Dalrymple et al.

Comment: @Atamiri, Thanks for the comments here. I understand little of the exchange, although the comments do illustrate for me the difficulties of communicating about these matters across fields.

Comment: @phipsgabler, thanks for your comments. See my message just above.

Answer (score 2):

Church's original formulation of type theory (based on λ-calculus) suggests binary branching. One way of dealing with this limitation is the use of linear logic, whose connective for tensor conjunction makes it possible to swap the arguments of linear implication. This is used in LFG, mainly because f-structures are isomorphic to dependency structures so the logical representations can be directly derived from them.

Yet another alternative is the formalism developed by Jerry Hobbs, who uses FOL with reification. His theory focuses on the level of pragmatics but he also has a syntactic component based on HPSG that meshes well with his logical forms. His theory is remarkable in that it is tractable using a technique of mathematical optimisation originally developed within operational research (and from a psycholinguistic perspective it's based on how the human mind works but that's another story).

P.S. I know both formalisms inside out so any detailed questions are welcome.

As as side note, type theory has nothing to do with branching so the question, as it's worded now, doesn't make sense. However (the original formulation of) type theory is based on λ-calculus which is incompatible with ternary branching so my answer addresses this discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is much I do not understand in what you write. Could you perhaps provide an example, for instance, an illustration of a logical structure of LFG and how it is isomorphic to an n-ary structure.

Comment: @TimOsborne If you take an exocentric structure for “students read books” in Russian, which is simply S:[NP V NP], the link to glue semantics is via the f-structure: [PRED read, SUBJ [“students”], OBJ [“books”]]. In glue semantics the corresponding rule would be λX.λY.read(X,Y):(↑SUBJ)σ  ⊸ (↑OBJ)σ ⊸ ↑σ. So they just use f-structures and linear implication to work around the limitation of λ-calculus. Note that the arity of the root node of the phrase structure is irrelevant. This method would work for any dep. formalism. Hobbs’ approach is much more flexible but this is how it works in LFG.

Comment: @TimOsborne I've added a note on the wording of the question, I hope I deciphered it correctly. In any case any additional questions are welcome.

Comment: Even in the lambda-calculus, the branching is not solely binary. The lambda-calculus has two operators: application (which is binary, as you point out), and abstraction (which is a binding unary operator). This means the trees terms form are not binary trees (and in fact have to be represented more sophisticatedly using structures like graphs with binding). I would also object to reducing "type theory" to the lambda-calculus, which is an extremely primitive notion and unlikely to very practical for linguistic purposes.

Comment: @varkor It’s about branching in phrase structure trees. The λ-calculus is used in formal semantics and it’s actually very powerful.

Comment: @Atamiri: I see, perhaps I misunderstood. If the question is about whether it is possible to represent n-ary branching phase structure trees using type theories (either using the structure of the type theory itself, or by encoding it), then the answer is yes, provided you choose a suitable type theory (I think this is what you allude to in your answer). However, if it is about the phase structure trees of (the syntax of) the type theories themselves (this seems to be what the other answer alludes to), the answer is less clear (though considering just "operator" and "argument" oversimplifies).

Comment: @varkor Yes, it’s about n-ary phrase structures. The other question (syntax trees of the theories themselves) is actually also very interesting but probably not for linguists (I know it from languages like Idris but that’s off topic here).

Comment: @Atamiri, thanks for your answer and the exchange with others. I have always been skeptical of the claim that LFG f-structures are isomorphic to dependency structures. The resemblance is certainly there, but the gulf between them is rather large.

Comment: @TimOsborne I think it just depends on exactly what you understand by dependency structures. In modern LFG there are no independent f-structures for function words (earlier versions did have them) so the isomorphism is certainly less obvious. But the point here is that for glue semantics (or other ways of building up type-theoretic forms) the shape of the syntactic structures isn’t important, it would work equally well for dependency trees with separate nodes for function words. There’s a paper on glue semantics for UDs.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is no, not n-ary branching, but rather binary branching.  As Atamiri's answer might suggest, the basic notion of type theory is that of a function -- the types are just means to that end.  If grammar is functional, complex expressions are built up by applying functions to arguments to obtain the values of functions at those arguments.  Two things, function and argument, combine to form a third thing: the (single) value.  That's binary branching.

One could, I suppose, allow grammatical functions to have 
more than one argument, but type theory seems to assume just one argument, and that's enough for me.

I have a way of introducing one-place functions into CFG (Context Free Grammar) which avoids the artificiality of type theory and introduces no additional computational complexity into grammar, but I'm afraid it's rather long-winded, and I'm not sure anyone would be interested.

Comment: I’d be interested ;) BTW I don’t think type theory is artificial (at least not more artificial than CFG or DG or any other formalism used in linguistics).

Comment: @Atamiri, Then please ask an appropriate question.  I can't write about it here, because it is not a type theory, so it would not be responsive to the question.

Comment: Done. I’m all ears.

Comment: Type theories are not just about operators (what you call functions). Considering operators alone ignores much of the other important structure: typing, variable binding, equations or reductions, polymorphism, dependency and so on. Likewise, the types are an intrinsic part of the structure: without them, you're simply talking about universal algebra.

Comment: The operators you describe are actually unary (taking a single argument): these are relatively uncommon in type theory. Consider even an operator for addition of natural numbers: this takes two arguments. Type theories usually have many operators of different arities. They are by no means limited to a single arity, or branching factor.

Comment: @varkor, Then why does a type, such as <e t>, have at most two parts?

Comment: @GregLee: ah, something I hadn't spotted earlier is [Wikipedia's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory#Linguistics) for type theory for linguistics. Indeed, you are right in that this type theory is binary. However, this is only one type theory that might be used: in general, type theories are more complex (e.g. those used in computer science). There are other examples used in linguistics, for example [Lambek's calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorial_grammar#Lambek_calculus), which has a different structure that is not limited to binary branching.

Comment: @varkor In fact, Montague’s notation with angle brackets simply denotes the function operator, which is binary, so <e,t> is the type of a unary function, <e,<e,t>> is the type of binary functions and <<e,t>,t> is the type of a higher-order function. In CS one would write e→e→t for the binary function type (since → associates to the right). Curiously, in the first papers on type theory by Church and Henkin, concatenation signifies the function operator (with the order of the arguments reversed).

Comment: @Greg Lee Thanks for your answer. It comports with my experience insofar as the matching of types to constituents in syntax always seems to be in terms of binary branching. The e and t version of type theory is the best example of this.

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand type theory and as described by lemontree, type theory necessarily construes syntactic structures as being generated in terms of one input and one output.

This is a misunderstanding. "Type theory" refers to a very general class of structures. Loosely, operators in type theory may be thought of as "n-ary functions". That is, they may take a fixed number of inputs and return a single output. The terms in a type theory thus have a tree structure. They are not limited to binary branching.

An example of a binary operator is `app : Fun(A, B) x B -> B`, which takes a term of type `Fun(A, B)` and a term of type `B` and returns a term of type `B`. An example of a ternay operator is `if : Bool x A x A -> A`, which takes a truth value, and two cases of the same type, and returns a term of the same type `A`. There are many examples of operators with different arities.

One confusion may be that there are many structures computer scientists classify as "type theories". The simply-typed lambda-calculus is a canonical example, but by no means the only one. (Though, even the simply-typed lambda-calculus has non-binary operators!)

> If there are versions of type theory that are compatible with n-ary branching, then what are they, and how widespread and accepted are those versions?

Most type theories have operators with a range of arities. Common theories include the simply-typed lambda-calculus, System F, Martin-Löf Type Theory, and others. All the type theories [listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory#Type_theories) are examples.

Possibly the most helpful way of thinking about the structure of terms in a type theory is as "structured trees with binding". Each term has a (n-ary branching) tree structure, but the form of the tree is restricted to those that are well-formed according to the rules of the type theory. Additionally, some vertices of the tree are "variables", which link back to a branch that binds them. I would recommend taking a look at a standard text book on Type theory, which will help give you an idea of the sort of structure that appears. [Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) is often one that is recommended for newcomers.

Comment: I think the question is about branching in phrase structures.

Comment: @Atamiri: I accept that I may have approached this at the wrong angle, but it still appears to me that the branching of phase structures is related to the branching factor of term trees in a type theory. If you want to use type theory to represent n-ary phase structures, then it certainly seems like you could make use a type theory with n-ary operators. Perhaps I am misunderstanding, though?

Comment: I don’t think it’s related, if only for the fact that it’s language-specific in CFG. That said, it’s related at the level of dependencies (dep. trees vs terms), but dependency trees have no constraints on arity. Maybe that’s what you meant.

Comment: I was thinking of representing the phase structure structure (of a given language) via the terms of a type theory (in which case, as I understand it, the given language would determine the arities of the branches, though some may be variadic). If you want to represent arbitrary languages using a single type theory, you would need to encode the structure of a grammar somehow, though then the branching factor is irrelevant.

Comment: @varkor Thanks for your answer. I of course believe that many versions of type theory are compatible with n-ary branching. I should have qualified my question, though, so that it focuses on versions of type theory that are actually used by syntacticians as they try to establish a one-to-one matching of semantic units to syntactic constituents. There seem to be few instances of linguists actually doing this. Binary branching everywhere is what one encounters instead. For that reason, I have always seen little value in type theory for natural language syntax.

Comment: @TimOsborne: ah, thank you for clarifying. In that case, my answer is answering a slightly different question. Perhaps there's an opportunity for someone to try overcoming these shortcomings with existing type theories in linguistics, as you mention, by employing a more expressive type theory from computer science :)